# Windows 10 went to hibernation/sleep all of a sudden

Tags: windows, windows-10, hibernate

Could somebody help me diagnose what happened please? I was using my computer and all of a sudden it went to hibernation or sleep. It never happened before in 7 years I've had this computer. The power button light was flashing blue and I couldn't turn it back on. I tried to move the mouse, press keys on the keyboard, press the power button, hold the power button for a few seconds - nothing. I had to unplug it and plug it back in.

I checked the event viewer and it says the following:

```
System:

03:28:40
Source: Service Control Manager
Information: The start type of the Background Intelligent Transfer Service service was changed from demand start to auto start.

03:28:42
Source: Kernel-Power
Information: The system is entering sleep. Sleep Reason: Application API

03:28:42
Source: Kernel-General
Information: The system time has changed to ‎2021‎-‎04‎-‎15T02:28:14.500000000Z from ‎2021‎-‎04‎-‎15T02:28:42.404571100Z. Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.

03:28:43
Source: Kernel-Power
Information: The system has resumed from sleep.

03:28:43
Source: Kernel-Power
Error: The system firmware has changed the processor's memory type range registers (MTRRs) across a sleep state transition (S5). This can result in reduced resume performance.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Application:

03:28:39
Information: svchost (3468,G,0) The beta feature EseDiskFlushConsistency is enabled in ESENT due to the beta site mode settings 0x800000.

03:28:40
Information: svchost (17848,G,0) The beta feature EseDiskFlushConsistency is enabled in ESENT due to the beta site mode settings 0x800000.
```

Comment: Your computer didn't go to sleep. If it were asleep, unplugging it would have lost any "slept" data. Your computer more likely experienced some sort of hardware fault or failure. Please collect more information.

Comment: @music2myear Thank you for your answer. What other information do I need to collect?